# How to select radio button using multi-mechanize python

Tags: python, automation, mechanize, mechanize-python

I have a simple php form and I would like to select the radio button using multimechanize, I'm able to select fill the text fields, but I'm not sure how to work with radio buttons or checkboxes...

I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
    # select first (zero-based) form on page
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    # set form field
    br.form['name'] = 'foo'
    br.form['email'] = 'foo@foo.com'
    br.form['gender'] = 'male'

<form method="post" action="/mechanize/index.php">
   Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="">
   <span class="error">* </span>
   <br><br>
   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="">
   <span class="error">* </span>
   <br><br>
   Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="">
   <span class="error"></span>
   <br><br>
   Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
   <br><br>
   Gender:
   <input type="radio" name="gender"   value="female">Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender"   value="male">Male
   <span class="error">* </span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I solved the issue with this br.form['gender'] = ['female']

Answer (score 0):

```
br.form.find_control(name="gender").value = 'male'
br.submit()
```

Comment: it didn't work, I think this is the error ListControl must set a sequence

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with `br.form['gender'] = ['female']`